# Do we say "line" or "lines"?

Tags: word-usage

Do we say "line" or "lines"?

The entry for line is:

> 10. Usu., lines. the words of an actor's part in a drama, musical comedy, etc.

It says it's usually plural, but they don't say when it's singular. Do we use the singular if the line is just a sentence? And do we use the plural when we're talking about more than two sentences?

For example:

> I said the following line "I am about to tell a really good one,
>   because I thought about this joke since the morning and the morning
>   thereafter, and I have refined it until this very last minute!" on stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are essentially correct.

**Lines** would either refer to more than one snippet of speech that an actor says *or* all the snippets of speech that an actor says in a scene/act/show. It can also refer to these snippets in a general sense -

> I am good at learning lines.

States that "I" is generally good at memorizing and remembering what they are supposed to say while acting.

---

**Line** would typically be used for just the next snippet of speech. I say snippet because sometimes the "line" is not a full sentence because people don't always talk in full sentences. If an actor forgets the very next snippet they are supposed to say while filming a music they may shout ["What's my line"](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/whats-my-line-actors-on-memorization/) with the singular as opposed to the plural.

Comment: Note that *a line* does not mean *a sentence*. A line of dialogue can be any number of sentences. A three-page monologue could be considered a line of dialogue. It's simply a period of talking that's uninterrupted by somebody (or something) else. Breaking it into sentences is just a way of visually representing what's being said. *What's my line?* just means *What do I say?*